Access Sharepoint with Python 3.6
I would like to access Share point file with python or Azure function, however when I import office365, it returns error
future feature annotations is not defined

Due to some reason I am force to use Python 3.6 and upgrading it will cause me trouble.
Would like to check if there is any alternative to retrieve or download Sharepoint files by using python without upgrading Python version
